# Several Ajax requests, all code runs sequentially

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code runs sequentially, one after another. I would like things to run in parallel. What do I need to change?

```
window.onload = function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Reports/GetTotalVisits"
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#visitCount').text(data.visitCount);
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Reports/GetTotalUsers",
        async: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#userCount').text(data.userCount);
    }); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Reports/VisitReport",
        async: true
    }).done(function (data) {
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("station-chart").getContext("2d");
        var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx2).Line(data);
    });

};
```

Comment: Are you very sure it does? I'd think the `done` callbacks are only called when the request's completed. -- In any case, what have you tried to change so far? There's several ways to do what you want; what's your specific problem with making it run parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following code runs sequentially, one after another.  I would like things to run in parallel...

I assume you mean you want the HTTP calls to overlap, e.g., start the second one while the first one is running rather than waiting, and start the third while the first two are running rather than waiting.

If so, that client-side code is fine. Those ajax requests are *started* sequentially, but will run in parallel. If you're seeing them happen only in series, look at the server side of the equation. Some server technologies will serialize requests from the same client, particularly if you're using "sessions" or similar. But that client code is fine (and `async: true` is never needed, that's the default).